# Chrome bug? Cursor changes on mouse down + move

Tags: css, google-chrome, mouse-cursor

In Chrome (I am using version 16.0.912.75 m on Win 7) I find that no matter what I have a cursor set as, as soon as I hold my left mouse button down and move the cursor then the cursor type is changed to `text` (even when there is no text anywhere on the page).

Is this a bug? Does anyone know how to get around it as it is making my drag and drop tool look a bit silly!

```css
div {
    background-color: lime;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor: wait;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Original JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KJfbs/**

**Edit**

As answered by @davgothic below, adding `-webkit-user-select: none;` will fix the issue when there is no text. However, should we position the element absolutely and place text behind it then the problem persists.

```css
div {
    background-color: lime;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    cursor: wait;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc quis eros mi, non tristique diam. Cras auctor posuere urna, porta egestas metus sollicitudin at. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Integer id arcu quis ipsum feugiat consequat id sit amet velit. Vivamus at quam quis lacus pellentesque egestas eu sed nulla. Vestibulum arcu augue, ultrices quis lobortis vehicula, molestie ut velit. Donec egestas lacus id diam euismod a lacinia lorem ultrices.

Vivamus non mi nunc. Pellentesque vitae sodales magna. In ac urna tortor. Quisque mattis mollis magna ultricies pellentesque. Mauris sed lorem eget sem imperdiet volutpat. Fusce fringilla pretium enim, eu ultricies justo fringilla in. Aliquam ac dui risus, ut eleifend tellus.

Nulla facilisi. Fusce nec leo lectus, in porttitor est. Etiam in posuere tellus. Maecenas viverra nibh et odio aliquam at aliquet arcu ultricies. Aliquam in arcu ac mi mollis ultricies vitae dapibus risus. Integer a arcu eu ipsum fermentum dignissim a vitae nunc. Pellentesque consectetur rutrum metus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi semper dapibus nunc. Mauris congue est sit amet neque condimentum nec fermentum massa sagittis. In bibendum cursus tortor quis scelerisque. Mauris est nisi, elementum eu scelerisque vel, placerat quis erat. Nam malesuada massa quis sem eleifend tempor eget ut erat.

Etiam egestas ligula nec odio molestie placerat. Donec nunc dolor, venenatis id iaculis vel, dapibus quis justo. Suspendisse sed nunc eget nunc luctus hendrerit eget at tortor. Quisque consectetur, eros eget dictum lobortis, erat nisl eleifend metus, egestas vulputate purus urna ut arcu. Nunc mollis tempor mi, quis commodo diam semper id. Nulla sed urna sit amet tellus consequat elementum. Maecenas cursus ipsum sit amet nunc laoreet quis placerat urna tempor. Maecenas tristique sodales posuere. Mauris scelerisque ornare tincidunt. Nulla tempus gravida orci, vel lacinia ante placerat ac. Donec gravida erat vitae elit suscipit ac ullamcorper lacus faucibus.

Aenean dictum elit eu nunc varius suscipit. Praesent ultrices, nunc ullamcorper posuere consectetur, purus ipsum dictum nisl, ultrices rhoncus nisl mauris sit amet dui. Donec convallis arcu eu nibh laoreet pulvinar. Sed euismod volutpat nibh eget faucibus. Maecenas interdum dapibus consequat. Sed sit amet leo lectus, euismod molestie nunc. Donec dui tellus, dignissim ut luctus non, facilisis eu magna. Phasellus a neque et dui luctus porttitor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec volutpat mollis dui, eget varius nunc gravida eu. Vivamus nibh erat, dapibus eu mattis blandit, sodales ut nisi. Vivamus pellentesque congue placerat. Pellentesque ultricies turpis vel odio imperdiet et facilisis leo viverra. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.    
</p>
```

**Original JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KJfbs/2/**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding `-webkit-user-select: none;` to the CSS for that element to prevent text selection.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KJfbs/1/

Personally I would also add these...

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
```

...for cross browser compatibility.

Comment: +1 - thanks, that does work for the example in my question. Unfortunately this does not seem to work when the div is positioned absolutely above text. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: I'm not really sure, as a last resort you could set `-webkit-user-select: none;` to the element containing the text. The user would lose the ability to select that text though. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/KJfbs/3/).

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that is an option. Thanks - I'll wait to see if anyone can offer advice on my edit before I accept your answer.

Comment: You might want to change the link in the edited question, for some reason it is pointing to my edit from my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks - I think I am having a slow day today

Comment: This answer worked for me. However; I found that having the Firebug console open in my JSFiddle (https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js) caused the cursor to change to the text cursor on mousedown, even with the answer implemented. If you are using JSFiddle with the Firebug console and are still getting the text cursor, try removing the console. Here is an example of the exact same JSFiddle: one [without the Firebug console](http://jsfiddle.net/KurtWM/ppez3/), and [one with the Firebug console](http://jsfiddle.net/KurtWM/JUqpw/). Click and drag the image in both to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that with -webkit-user-select: none; the problem persists if you put anything else in the page. For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/KJfbs/237/

Anyway I think jQuery preventDefault solves the problem in any case:
http://jsfiddle.net/KJfbs/241/

preventDefault avoids the default behavior that is change to cursor text.
Then I can control and put any cursor I want: $(this).css("cursor","wait");

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    $('#lime').mousedown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).css("cursor","wait"); 
    }).on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).css("cursor","default");
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="lime"></div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

CSS:

```
#lime {
    background-color: lime;
    height: 100px; width: 300px;
    cursor: wait;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
```